# Is there any way to merge coverage data?

Tags: c++, gcc, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I have multiple copies of my `cpp` program (on different physical machines) that will be tested by people-testers. I compiled program with `gcc` coverage flags (-ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -O0 etc.) and want to analyze gcov coverage. So the question: Is there any automatic approach / tool to combine coverage infos from different test-case usages of program.

Of course there will be intersections in coverage reports and that would be great if such an intersections can be ignored with respect to situation in which it intersections made.

Comment: You can use a hosted product which merges reports flawlessly: Codecov.io -- 
http://docs.codecov.io/docs/flags

Comment: You can also use the add tracefile option available in [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/lcov.1.php)